# Convert json structure to drop-down list using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a json that has the property `categories[]`, and inside each `categories` there is a `subCategories[]`; and for each`subCategories` there is a `subSubCategories`. I would want to generate the dropdowns based on the given json structure.

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "men": "Mens",
      "subCat": [
        {
          "topWear": "Top Wear",
          "subSubCat": [
            {
              "tshirts": "T-shirts",
              "otherAttributes": [
                {
                  "fitting": [
                    "type 1",
                    "type 2",
                    "type 3"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "washCare": [
                    "wash Care 1",
                    "wash care 2"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "shirt": "Shirt",
              "otherAttributes": [
                {
                  "fitting": [
                    "type 4",
                    "type 5",
                    "type 6"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "washCare": [
                    "wash Care 4",
                    "wash care 5"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "bottomWear": "Bottom Wear"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "women": "Women",
      "subCat": [
        {
          "topWear": "Top Wear",
          "subSubCat": [
            {
              "tshirts": "T-shirts",
              "otherAttributes": [
                {
                  "fitting": [
                    "w-type 1",
                    "type 2",
                    "type 3"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "washCare": [
                    "w-wash Care 1",
                    "wash care 2"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "shirt": "Shirt",
              "otherAttributes": [
                {
                  "fitting": [
                    "w-type 4",
                    "type 5",
                    "type 6"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "washCare": [
                    "w-wash Care 4",
                    "wash care 5"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "bottomWear": "Bottom Wear"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "kids": "Kids"
    }
  ]
}
```

*For example:*

- Initially first drop-down should be populated with `mens`,`women`,`kids` options.
- Next on main category selection, second drop-down should populate with `subCat` options.
- Next, on `subCat` selection, third drop-down should populate with `subSubCat`options.

How can I achieve this using angular?

Comment: if your JSON is mapped to an object, then you can just use `ng-options` to populate the dropdowns;  when you select an option from the first dropdown, it's `ng-model` will be one of the objects from the first level of the array, along with all it's possible options for the second `ng-options`, and so on.

Comment: I tried to list main category, but I am unable to populate, https://jsfiddle.net/08z4kb09/6/

Answer (score 1):

First of all your example is not working. And your structure is not perfect for this situation. I have created an example for you : [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/08z4kb09/22/)

You can use it like:

html

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" ng-app="main">
    <hr>
    <select ng-model="selectedFirst" ng-options="first.name for first in categories track by first">
    <option value="">Select Account</option>
  </select>
  <select ng-model="selectedSecond"  ng-options="second.name for second in selectedFirst.categories track by second">
    <option value="">Select Account</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

js

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  /**
   * Main module of the main
   */
  angular
    .module('main', []);
})();


(function(){
    'use strict'

  angular
    .module('main')
    .controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);

  /** @ngInject */
  function DemoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.categories = [
        {
        "name" : "Mens",
        "categories" : [
            {
                "name" : "Top Wear",
                "categories" : [
                    {

                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
      }
    ];
  }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer, but your fiddle is not working, getting `Error 500`

Comment: Second drop-down list is not working, when i add more items in main category array. When I select `mens`, then also w-top wear is getting populated int second drop-down list.   Check here https://jsfiddle.net/08z4kb09/23/